# How to pick contact's non default phone number?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am starting contact picker activity to get phone number

```
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    i.type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT)
```

If contact has no default number, phone number picker dialog is shown

[image]

If a contact has default number, phone number picker dialog is not shown and default number is taken by default.

So my question: How to show phone picker dialog even if a contact has default number?

Comment: have you tried this? for intent type
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

Comment: @LokeshDesai, thank you for your suggestion. I have tried it, but phone number picker dialog is not shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the Phone-Picker, use the Contact-Picker, and show the phones dialog yourself.

```
Intent intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_CONTACT);
```

...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        long contactId = getContactIdFromUri(contactUri);
        List<String> phones = getPhonesFromContactId(contactId);
        showPhonesDialog(phones);
    }
}

private long getContactIdFromUri(Uri contactUri) {
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID}, null, null, null);
    long id = -1;
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        id = cur.getLong(0);
    }
    cur.close();
    return id;
}

private List<String> getPhonesFromContactId(long contactId) {
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                    new String[]{CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                    CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
    List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String phone = cur.getString(0);
        phones.add(phone);
    }
    cur.close();
    return phones;
}

private void showPhonesDialog(List<String> phones) {
    String[] phonesArr = phones.toArray(new String[0]);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Select a phone:");

    builder.setItems(phonesArr, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i("Phone Selection", "user selected: " + phonesArr[which]);
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. Can add selection argument to get one contact's numbers. Now it is taking all contacts numbers. Cursor cur = activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);